# sed -e '$!d' not working as expected?

Tags: sed, io-redirection

When I run:

```
sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -t
```

I get back:

```
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I just want the last line so I run:

```
sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -t | sed -e '$!d'
```

But I get back the same as without sed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your command possibly outputs to stderr instead of stdout. To redirect stderr to stdout:

```
sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -t 2>&1 | sed -e '$!d'
```

If you only want the last line of your output, you can also use `tail -n 1` instead of `sed`.

Comment: yep, that was it